# Jest Mock and Rest Data Set

Tags: jestjs

I have a some functions that are processing the following set of data.

```
const cartStructure = () => {
    cartStructure = {
        orders: 
        [{orderID: 0, burger: 0,fries: 0,drink: 0,},
        {orderID: 0,burger: 0,fries: 0,drink: 0}
        ]
    }
}
beforeEach(() => {
    cartStructure.mockClear()
});
```

I assumed the way to reset data to initial form is with beforeEach(), as I tried above.

Can someone advise?

I did try to make a function out of that data set, but essentially all I need is that data reset to inial state, every time I give the cartStructure parameterto my function.

Update

```
const cart = {
    orders: 
    [{orderID: 0, burger: 0,fries: 0,drink: 0,},
    {orderID: 0,burger: 0,fries: 0,drink: 0}
    ]
}

module.exports.cartStructure = () => {
    return cart;
};
```

Comment: *reset data to initial form* - it's unclear what is initial form because the snippet you provided isn't workable, mockClear is for Jest spies. Is it `{ orders: ...` or else? *I did try to make a function out of that data set* - what did you try?

Comment: The data that you see it is the initial form. I have a few methods that alter that data. I need that data to be as is before each method executes.

Comment: I think the confusion was dues to the fact that I wasn't returning after the first ``` and that was taking out the const.

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeEach(() => {
     cartStructure();
});
```

This is what worked for me.